# Sed / Awk : replace the first occurrence of a pattern with the content of another file

Tags: awk, sed

With sed, I'm trying to replace the **first** occurrence of a comment in a script, like :

`#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT`

by the content of a second file ($file_content) into another third file (/base.sh).

So, according to many docs, the string should be quite simple, something like :

`sed "s|\#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT|$file_content|" /base.sh`

But I always end up with errors like :

`sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated s' command`

or similar messages, also tried different delimiters, even with Awk instead, but without success, it seems to be fine after escaping the # in the search pattern, but I still can't get the file content as a variable in Sed.

Any ideas, either with Sed or Awk ?

**Edit : --------------------**

@Sundeep @James Brown:

Don't want to mix the subjects nor to be long :) the response to you clarification request is in bold at the end of this edit, but just to elaborate the context, my case is a Docker entrypoint script in bash (for a base Docker image) called `/root/test/`**base** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT

if [[ -e "/root/test/custom" ]]; then

    printf "\n\n#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT\n"  >> /root/test/custom

    # Code from whjm's reply below (actually works but appends shebangs from custom files)
    sed -e '0,/^#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT/!b; /^#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT/{ r /root/test/custom' -e 'd; }' /root/test/base.sh >> /root/test/base2.sh

    mv /root/test/base2.sh /root/test/base.sh
    rm -f /root/test/custom

fi
```

I just want to let users drop another bash script of their own on a specific path (say `/root/test/`**custom**), for example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'My 2nd bash code'
```

The first script above (**base**) should insert the content of the **custom** file at `#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT` position (in the base script itself, without removing this search string), like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'My 2nd bash code'

#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT

if [[ -e "/root/test/custom" ]]; then

    printf "\n\n#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT\n"  >> /root/test/custom

    # Code from whjm's reply below
    sed -e '0,/^#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT/!b; /^#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT/{ r /root/test/custom' -e 'd; }' /root/test/base.sh >> /root/test/base2.sh

    mv /root/test/base2.sh /root/test/base.sh
    rm -f /root/test/custom

fi
```

If another user later drops another custom script at the same path, we should have the code of this third custom script appended like this  :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'My 2nd bash code'
echo 'My 3rd bash code'
#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT

if [[ -e "/root/test/custom" ]]; then
# ... and so on
```

Regarding the shebangs from custom files, it's not a real issue if they are appended to the base file, the sed code from @whjm works as expected but appends them, while (surprisingly) both awk codes from @James Brown already (and gracefully :) ignore all additional shebangs from custom files (probably because they also start with # as the #ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT search string) but **currently partly preprend the code like :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'My 3rd bash code'
echo 'My 2nd bash code'
#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT
```

**while I'm trying to get it appended like :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'My 2nd bash code'
echo 'My 3rd bash code'
#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT
```

**So, in short, @Sundeep, if you could just give me an updated version of your awk code for this, it would be perfect ! :D** (couldn't find a way to invert this...) Thanks a lot.

Code from your previous post :

```
NR==FNR { b=b (FNR==1?"":ORS) $0; next }
{ r=r (FNR==1?"":ORS) $0 } #ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT
END { sub(/\#[^\n]+/,r,b); print b}
```

Comment: you will get errors if `$file_content` has newlines, the `|` character, etc... if you can add a small made up content of `base.sh` and `file_content`, it will help in providing you a solution... especially create a sample having multiple `#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT` and show the expected output

Comment: @Sundeep : my answer on the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using **GNU** sed:

```
[STEP 101] # cat file1
11
xx // replace me
44
xx // don't replace me
55
[STEP 102] # cat file2
22
33
[STEP 103] # sed -e '0,/^xx/!b; /^xx/{ r file2' -e 'd }' file1
11
22
33
44
xx // don't replace me
55
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks a lot ! For other readers, `xx` in the code above is the string to search and replace (`#ENTRYPOINT_CONTENT` in my case)